# How do you edit/modify these OOTB workflows? I can't see them in SPD 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, share

How do you edit these OOTB workflows?
I do not see them in the SPD 2010 Workflows. Are they elsewhere?
I would like to modify some of the email/notifications it sends.
I also would like to toggle some of the fields depending on the outcome.
And lastly update the form itself.

Where may they be?

[image]

Comment: You can't modify the ootb workflows, but you can create your own and add these variables at the initiation form.